# Paypal multiple IPN same merchant on set express checkout

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, recurring-billing

I have 2 websites which need to use `IPN` notifications from paypal.

Is there a way through the API to set up where to call the `IPN` url from a recurring purchase?

I have seen the API from **`CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile`** and **`SetExpressCheckout`**, and none of these have a field to set the notifyurl from a different IPN.

How can I make my 2 sites have recurring payments using `IPN` notifications?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it creating a base IPN url and from there redirect the IPN request from paypal using 302 redirects. It seems that not every paypal transaction allows to set the IPN url, specially for concurrent payments.

This post help me to create the broadcasting schema http://codeseekah.com/2012/02/11/how-to-setup-multiple-ipn-receivers-in-paypal/